# Protobuf-net asking for TypeModel.CS when used with Generics for deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protobuf-net, b-plus-tree

I have billions of objects that I'm trying to structure them in a B+Tree serialized to HDD. I'm using [BPlusTree](http://csharptest.net/projects/bplustree/) library for the data structure and [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for serialization/deserialization. In this regard I define my classes as:

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public class B<C, M>
        where C : IComparable<C>
        where M : IData<C>
    {
        internal B()
        {
            lambda = new List<Lambda<C, M>>();
            omega = 0;
        }

        internal B(C coordinate)
        {
            lambda = new List<Lambda<C, M>>();
            e = coordinate;
            omega = 0;
        }

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        internal C e { set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        internal List<Lambda<C, M>> lambda { private set; get; }

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        internal int omega { set; get; }
    }


[ProtoContract]
public class Lambda<C, M>
    where C : IComparable<C>
    where M : IData<C>
{
    internal Lambda() { }

    internal Lambda(char tau, M atI)
    {
        this.tau = tau;
        this.atI = atI;
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    internal char tau { private set; get; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    internal M atI { private set; get; }
}
```

and I define my serializers/deserializers as following:

```
public class BSerializer<C, M> : ISerializer<B<C, M>>
        where C : IComparable<C>
        where M : IData<C>
    {
        public B<C, M> ReadFrom(System.IO.Stream stream)
        {
            return Serializer.Deserialize<B<C, M>>(stream);
        }

        public void WriteTo(B<C, M> value, System.IO.Stream stream)
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<B<C, M>>(stream, value);
        }
    }
```

Then I use them all in a B+Tree ([This library](http://csharptest.net/projects/bplustree/)) data structure which is defined as:

```
var options = new BPlusTree<C, B<C, M>>.OptionsV2(CSerializer, BSerializer);
var myTree = new BPlusTree<C, B<C, M>>(options);
```

The B+Tree is defined as a dictionary of key-value pairs. My `key` (i.e., `C`) is an integer and the serializer is the default serializer of `BPlusTree` library. My `Value` is a custom object `B<C,M>` that is serialized using `protobuf-net`.

My problem surely happens, but almost at random times; always searching for `Keys`, it suddenly starts deserializing the `Value` and at the first call of `B<C, M> ReadFrom(System.IO.Stream stream)` it asks for `TypeModel.CS` and `ProtoReader.CS` files. I get both packages from `NuGet`.

Comment: Asking for a file just means it caught an exception and you have the debugging symbols; what is the actual exception message?

Comment: @MarcGravell the exception is: `Invalid field in source data: 0`

Comment: that *usually* means the actually data is invalid - what is the wider context here? what are you serializing to / deserializing from?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm serializing/deserializing a kind of converter for a collection of [BED files](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format1). I serialize all data to a local file, and deserialize at demand. But at first request of deserialization I get this error :(

Comment: have you an example of the code that opens the files and calls serialize / deserialize? I strongly suspect the error is around there...

Comment: @MarcGravell How can I check for data validity ? Is there any other possible reason for this issue ? How is it possible for data to get corrupted ?

Comment: hence why I would like to see the code that opens the files and calls serialize / deserialize ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell actually the process of opening the file is taken care by `BPlusTree`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the code, it looks like the calling code assumes serializations are aware of their own length; from the source:

```
foreach (T i in items)
    _serializer.WriteTo(i, io);
```

Protobuf messages *are not self-terminating* - the google protobuf specification defines append===merge. As such, you'll need to prefix messages. Fortunately, you should be able to just switch to `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` and `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix`. If that doesn't work, it would be worth putting together a fully reproducible example so that it can be investigated.

Comment: Thanks indeed @MarcGravell, this saved me after almost 10 days of back-and-forth on my hellish code; suspecting almost everything (you won't believe me that I was suspecting also the inheritance and polymorphism ;-)) Thanks.

Comment: @Hamed wow, did that fix it? I knew that the calling code was problematic, but I'm pleased and somewhat surprised if that was the only pain point...

Comment: yeah that solved the "big" issue :) This time it keeps giving `Attempted to read past the end of the stream` which presumably is going to be the next nightmare (I hope NOT) :D

Comment: @Marc, Thank you for answering this, you are correct about the library's expectation.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach to solving this problem, you can also aggregate the behavior of the built-in serailizers:

```
    class BSerializer<C, M> : ISerializer<B<C, M>>
        where C : IComparable<C>
        where M : IData<C>
    {
        public B<C, M> ReadFrom(System.IO.Stream stream)
        {
            byte[] value = CSharpTest.Net.Serialization.PrimitiveSerializer.Bytes.ReadFrom(stream);
            return Serializer.Deserialize<B<C, M>>(new MemoryStream(value));
        }

        public void WriteTo(B<C, M> value, System.IO.Stream stream)
        {
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize<B<C, M>>(memory, value);
                CSharpTest.Net.Serialization.PrimitiveSerializer.Bytes.WriteTo(memory.ToArray(), stream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: This approach can be a performance problem due to the unnecessary copies of data; however, it can help resolve the issue.

Another possibility is simply defined the tree as `BPlusTree<TKey, byte[]>` and provide the `PrimitiveSerializer.Bytes` as the value serializer.  This places the burden of object serialization on the caller which can be a very good thing.  The reason this can be beneficial is two fold:

1. Your object model is no longer required to be immutable.
2. If the deserialization of the object is expensive, this may perform better in random-access uses.

For other common serialization issues and some examples please read the following article:

http://csharptest.net/1230/bplustree-and-custom-iserializer-implementations/

Comment: I agree with your point "unnecessary copies" for 1st solution, I also think the 2nd idea is good. However, I have a minor concern: can I call this a 2-step (de)serialization that is (1) my value object to `byte[]` and (2) serialize `byte[]`?

Comment: @Hamed You wind up serializing to byte[] to put it in, and deserialize from byte[] when reading.

Comment: my apologies in advance ... but could you please help me understand how I can "wind up serializing to `byte[]`" without using `Formatter` ?